# Xcode submission error

Tags: xcode, submission

I'm trying to submit a Mac OS X Application to the App Store but I'm currently stuck.
I've created and installed the 3rd Party Mac Developer Application and Installer certificate and added to Xcode the provisioning profile for Production.

When I Archive my application and, after validation, try to submit it, I can't choose the "Application" options 'cause the only option I can take is:"No Value".

I've tried to create a package (With "share" button) and test its installation process as suggest it by the Apple Documentation and the process terminate successfully.

But when I try to submit the package through the Application Loader app, I receive the error:"There is no embedded Java executable. Please reinstall Xcode Developer Tools".

The fact is that I've already reinstalled all the Xcode Developer Tools (I was using a beta version before) from the App Store.

Any ideas?

Comment: obviously my application status is "Waiting for Upload"

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Xcode 4.2 and as a pre-release version? If so, try using Xcode 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Application Loader" in Developer/Applications/Utilities. The tool that is present under xcode is full of bugs. You will need to give it the .app generated as a product by XCode. Did that help ? Annother thing you can try is to reject yourself the app into iTunes Connect, then set it again as "ready for download". It won't force you to upgrade your app version.